# Insert and update in one form

Tags: php

yesterday my question regarding insert and update in one form i did but data are inserted and when i am clicking on edit link which is available on displayp.php it display all data's in field but when i am update any data and click on submit button its not update but it insert data next time in database and i am getting multiple record in database. Actually I had put insert and update in if condition when i am updating its not moving in else part so please help me... Thank You..

```
<div id="page-wrapper" >
<div id="page-inner">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Add Product</h2>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- /. ROW  -->
<hr />
<div class="row">
<?php 
   include('config.php');
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
   {
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])=='POST')
   {

   echo "working"; 
   $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
   $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
   $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
   $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"];  

   if($fileType=="application/pdf"){
   if($fileSize<=200){

   //New file name
   $random=rand(1111,9999);
   $newFileName=$random.$fileName;

   //File upload path
   $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;

   //function for upload file

   if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
   {
   echo "Successful<BR>"; 
   echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 
   echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
   echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
   }
   else
   {


   echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
   }
   }
   else
   {


   return false;


   echo "You can only upload a pdf doc file.";
   }  


       echo "here downld";


   $updates = isset($_POST['updates']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';

       $catnm=$_POST['catnm'];
       $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
       $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];

       //$updates=$_POST['downld'];
       $date=$_POST['date'];



   $query=("insert into addproduct(catnm,prodnm,prod_dtl,pdf,downld,date)


   values('$catnm','$prodnm','$prod_dtl','$uploadPath','$updates','$date')");
       $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
       echo"record inserted";
       if($result)
       {
           header("location:addProduct.php");
       }
   }

   }
   }
   else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
   {
   if(isset($_GET['id']))
   {

   $id = $_GET['id'];
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {




   $updates['downld'] = isset($_POST['downld']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
   $cat['catnm']=$_POST['catnm'];
   $prodnm['prodnm']=$_POST['prodnm'];
   $prod_dtl['prod_dtl']=$_GET['prod_dtl'];
   $pdf['pdf']=$_GET['pdf'];
   $downld['downld']=$_GET['downld'];
   $date['date']=$_GET['date'];



   $query3=mysql_query("update addproduct set catnm='$cat',            
   prodnm='$prodnm',prod_dtl='$prod_dtl'


   ,pdf='$pdf',downld='$updates',date='$date' where id='$id'");

   if($query3)
   {
       header('location:addProduct.php');
   }
   }


   $query1=mysql_query("select * from addproduct where id='$id'");
   $query4=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
   //echo "<pre>";
   //print_r($query4);
   }
   }
   ?>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="panel-body">
      <form role="form"  method="post" 
         enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="myform" >
         <br/>
         <label>Select Category:</label>      
         <div class="form-group">
            <?php
               include('config.php');


               $query1=mysql_query("select catnm from addcategory");
               ?>
            <select class=form-control m-b-10 name=catnm id=catnm >
            <?php
               echo"<option>---Select---</option required>";
               while($query=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
               {

                  $selectedCat = '';
                  if($query[catnm] == $query4['catnm'])
                  {
                      $selectedCat = "selected";
                  }



               echo "<option value='$query[catnm]' $selectedCat >$query[catnm]</option>";


               }

               ?>                                    
            </select>
            <br/>                
            <div class="form-group"> 
               <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                  id="prodnm" placeholder="Product Name" name="prodnm" required 
                  value= " <?php if(isset($query4['prodnm'])){echo $query4['prodnm'];}?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">        
               <textarea class="form-control" id="catdtl" 
                  name="prod_dtl" placeholder="Product Detail"  
                  "rows="10" cols="62" required>
               <?php if(isset($query4['prod_dtl'])){
                  echo $query4['prod_dtl'];} ?>
               </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="exampleInputFile">PDF File</label>
               <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" 
                  accept="application/pdf" name="filepdf" required >  
               file : <?php if(isset($query4['pdf'])){
                  echo $query4['pdf'];} ?>                        
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
               <label>
               <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="updates" required 
                  <?php  if(isset($query4['downld'])) 
                     { if($query4['downld'] == 'Yes') 
                     echo "checked='checked'"; echo $query4['downld'];} 
                                 ?> />
               Is Downloadable <br />
               </label>
            </div>
            <input type="text"  
               placeholder="Date of Upload" id="datepicker-7" 
               name="date"  value="<?php if(isset($query4['date'])){
                  echo $query4['date'];}?>" required  />
            <div style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:40px;width:650px;">
               <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" tabindex="2"/>
               <hr/>
      </form>
      </div>
      <!-- /. ROW  -->
      </div>
      <!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
   </div>
   <!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered you yesterday, but you not added an hidden input with id. This you can do?

> [insert and update in one form in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376615/insert-and-update-in-one-form-in-php)

Also, How you imagine this **post in get**?

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

$id = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

*  *  *
}
}
```

Comment: if it working select answer as accepted and questions will be considered resolved